# Error in accessing webcam with Python's OpenCV module

Tags: python, opencv, object-detection

**Python 3.7.6, opencv-python 4.4.0, Windows 10**

Code

```
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
while True:
    success, frame = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow("frame", frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(0) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
```

I want to access my external usb webcam. I am new to opencv and got the following error message.

```
C:\Users\92311\PycharmProjects\ObjectDetector\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/92311/PycharmProjects/ObjectDetector/main.py
[ WARN:0] global C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-2b5g8ysb\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_msmf.cpp (435) `anonymous-namespace'::SourceReaderCB::~SourceReaderCB terminating async callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/92311/PycharmProjects/ObjectDetector/main.py", line 5, in <module>
    cv2.imshow("frame", frame)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.4.0) C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-2b5g8ysb\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:376: error: (-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function 'cv::imshow'


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Can any one explain what's the real problem.

Comment: Did you look at this [OpenCV Python: cv2.VideoCapture can only find 2 of 3 cameras](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49663474/opencv-python-cv2-videocapture-can-only-find-2-of-3-cameras-windows-camera-app/49901961)?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you don't have a second camera try:

`cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)`

Answer (score 1):

`cv2.VideoCapture(0,cv2.CAP_DSHOW)`
if it is windows7 Try this it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```py
if cv2.waitkey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
    break
```

note that its `waitkey(1)` and not `0` as argument.

Answer (score -1):

first try to change cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1) to cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
id still error issue. then uninstall opencv

```
pip uninstall opencv-python
```

reinstall it

```
pip install opencv-python
```

it works for me